# GeoServer 2.23.0 - Error uploading grib2 file as store

Tags: geoserver, netcdf, grib-2

I am attempting to add HRRR met data (grib2 file) to GeoServer through the gui as a store. I have installed all needed extensions. I have gotten this working for one file but cannot add in more grib2 files. If I remove ncx3 and gbx9 files for the successfully uploaded grib2 file and attempt to readd, I get an error.

How do I resolve this error with uploading grib2 files to GeoServer?

Source hrrr data:
[Source data example](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/high-resolution-rapid-refresh/hrrr.20220101/conus;tab=objects?prefix=&forceOnObjectsSortingFiltering=false&pageState=(%22StorageObjectListTable%22:(%22f%22:%22%255B%255D%22)))
(download hrrr.t00z.wrfnatf00.grib2 as an example)

The grib2 file opens correctly in panoply. It has many dimensions, some I do not need.

Versions:

- GeoServer: 2.23.0
- Tomcat: 9.0.71
- Ubuntu:22.04

GRIB2 error:

```
Caused by: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon cannot be cast to class [B (org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @15b986cd; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFAccess.<init>(NetCDFAccess.java:130)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFDriver.connect(NetCDFDriver.java:93)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.impl.DefaultFileDriver.process(DefaultFileDriver.java:231)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFReader.<init>(NetCDFReader.java:156)
    ... 155 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon cannot be cast to class [B (org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @15b986cd; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.geotools.imageio.netcdf.NetCDFImageReader.setInput(NetCDFImageReader.java:307)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageReader.setInput(ImageReader.java:380)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFAccess.<init>(NetCDFAccess.java:119)
    ... 158 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon cannot be cast to class [B (org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @15b986cd; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.geotools.imageio.netcdf.NetCDFImageReader.initIndex(NetCDFImageReader.java:414)
    at org.geotools.imageio.netcdf.NetCDFImageReader.init(NetCDFImageReader.java:541)
    at org.geotools.imageio.netcdf.NetCDFImageReader.setInput(NetCDFImageReader.java:305)
    ... 160 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon cannot be cast to class [B (org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @15b986cd; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.geotools.data.h2.H2DialectBasic.encodeValue(H2DialectBasic.java:190)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insertSQL(JDBCDataStore.java:4420)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insertNonPS(JDBCDataStore.java:2040)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insert(JDBCDataStore.java:1862)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.flush(JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.java:130)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.write(JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.java:102)
    at org.geotools.data.InProcessLockingManager$1.write(InProcessLockingManager.java:302)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureStore.addFeature(ContentFeatureStore.java:295)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureStore.addFeatures(ContentFeatureStore.java:250)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.catalog.CoverageSlicesCatalog.addGranules(CoverageSlicesCatalog.java:380)
    at org.geotools.imageio.netcdf.NetCDFImageReader.initIndex(NetCDFImageReader.java:391)
    ... 162 more
21:30:40 INFO   [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:///opt/data/met/test/hrrr.20220101_conus_hrrr.t00z.wrfnatf01.grib2
```

Some things I have attempted to resolve error:

- Clear cache in server status
- Remove generated ncx3 and gbx9 files
- Include the idx file for grib2 in same folder
- Check file / dir permissions
- Update Java 11 to 17
- Change Tomcat version to 8
- Add crs Projection to data/user_projections/netcdf.projections.properties
  in container with projection
- Change jts core version to jts-core-1.18.2.jar
- Change NetCDF jar version to netcdf-4.2.20.jar (error doing this)
- Add Java heap (EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms8G -Xmx8G)
- Convert grib2 file to netcdf and upload netcdf as store (tried with compressed and uncompressed NetCDF with different error below. NC file dimensions = y, x, hybrid. Variable names all changed)
- Name store same name as source file

Comment: I'd leave JTS alone and install Java 11 and try again.

Comment: @IanTurton I am currently on Java 11, do you think this is an error with the number of dimensions in the grib2 file?

Comment: No idea  I'm afraid I don't use grib, did you go back to a clean install?

Comment: Unfortunately, you deleted *all* the questions. Please add one specific question.

Comment: @Vince I think my question is pretty clear. Why am I getting this error with grib2 files and how do I resolve it